# PHP/MySQL - Combine select queries

Tags: php, mysql

i have 3 MySQL queries, like so;

```
$q1 = "SELECT id,date,quantity1,quantity2,total FROM test WHERE type='pencil' AND MONTH(date)='$month' AND YEAR(date)='$year' ORDER BY id";
$r1 = mysql_query($q1);

$q2 = "SELECT SUM(total) AS stotal FROM test WHERE type='pencil' AND MONTH(date)='$month' AND YEAR(date)='$year' GROUP BY id ORDER BY id";
$r2 = mysql_query($q2);

$q2 = "SELECT AVG(ROUND(total)) AS atotal FROM test WHERE type='pencil' AND MONTH(date)='$month' AND YEAR(date)='$year' GROUP BY id ORDER BY id";
$r2 = mysql_query($q2);
```

how can i combine these 3 queries? so i can use it in one while loop. i've tried the multiple statement in while loop, like so;

```
$lastr = '';
while ((list($id, $date, $q1, $q2, $total) = mysql_fetch_row($r1)) && ($row =  mysql_fetch_array($r2)) && ($row =  mysql_fetch_array($r3)))  {
if ($lastr != $id ) {
    if ($lastr != '') {
        // output row
    echo "<tr><th>$lastr</th><th>$stotal</th><th>$atotal</th><td>";
        echo join('</td><td>', $rowdata) . "</td></tr>\n";
    }
    $rowdata = $empty;
    $lastr = $id;
}
$rowdata[$rdate]  = $q1 .= '</td><td>' . $q2 .= '</td><td>' . $total;
}
```

when i only use the 1st query everything is being printed on my table, but when i add the 2 additional "and" statements the output is being limited. 
btw, im trying to produce a dynamic column and row which works only if i use the first query in while loop. thanks

---

Big thanks to: raheel shan

The answer to my question was:

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.date,
  t.quantity1,
  t.quantity2,
  t.total,
  lt.stotal,
  lt.atotal
FROM test as t
  left join (select
           id,
           SUM(total)   AS stotal,
           AVG(ROUND(total)) AS atotal
         from test
         WHERE type = 'pencil'
         AND MONTH(date) = '$month'
         AND YEAR(date) = '$year'
         GROUP BY id) as lt
    on lt.id = t.id
WHERE type = 'pencil'
    AND MONTH(date) = '$month'
    AND YEAR(date) = '$year'
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: do you know how to do sub-queries?

Comment: If you're going to use `mysql_query`, which you really shouldn't unless you have an exceptionally good reason, you need to [escape](http://bobby-tables.com/php) **any** and **all** values going into your queries.

Comment: @raheel, answer accepted. as much i wanted to vote it up like hundreds times i wont let me, needs more rep to do so. :(, anyways i wont leave this topic until i have voted up your answer. again thank you very much ^_^.

Comment: well i recommend that is simple the first one is derieved query you can do with second which is faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this single derieved query

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.date,
  t.quantity1,
  t.quantity2,
  t.total,
  lt.stotal,
  lt.atotal
FROM test as t
  left join (select
           id,
           SUM(total)   AS stotal,
           AVG(ROUND(total)) AS atotal
         from test
         WHERE type = 'pencil'
         AND MONTH(date) = '$month'
         AND YEAR(date) = '$year'
         GROUP BY id) as lt
    on lt.id = t.id
WHERE type = 'pencil'
    AND MONTH(date) = '$month'
    AND YEAR(date) = '$year'
ORDER BY id
```

Or this is more simple

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.date,
  t.quantity1,
  t.quantity2,
  t.total,
  SUM(lt.stotal) AS stotal,
  AVG(ROUND(lt.atotal)) AS atotal
FROM test as t
  left join test as lt
    on lt.id = t.id
WHERE type = 'pencil'
    AND MONTH(date) = '$month'
    AND YEAR(date) = '$year'
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: hi, the first solution works like a charm and exactly what i needed. the second solution throws an error "#1052 - Column 'total' in field list is ambiguous". im using solution one. thanks a bunch -nublet P.S: im waiting for my rep to increase to accept your answer.

Comment: it should be t.total sorry

Answer (score 0):

U can combine like this...........

```
SELECT id,date,quantity1,quantity2,total,(SELECT SUM(total)  FROM test WHERE type='pencil' AND MONTH(date)='$month' AND YEAR(date)='$year' GROUP BY id ORDER BY id) as sum_total,(SELECT AVG(ROUND(total))  FROM test WHERE type='pencil' AND MONTH(date)='$month' AND YEAR(date)='$year' GROUP BY id ORDER BY id") as avg_total FROM test WHERE type='pencil' AND MONTH(date)='$month' AND YEAR(date)='$year' ORDER BY id";
```

Comment: hi, this returns error #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Answer (score 0):

You can add the queries together like this

```
$q1 = "SELECT id,date,quantity1,quantity2,total,AVG(ROUND(total)) AS stotal, AVG(ROUND(total)) AS atotal FROM test WHERE type='pencil' AND MONTH(date)='$month' AND YEAR(date)='$year' GROUP BY  id,date,quantity1,quantity2,total,stotal,atotal ORDER BY id";
$r1 = mysql_query($q1);
```

The reason you need the group by clause is because the you can not have non-aggragate selects outside a group by statement is aggragate functions exist in the select.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q1 = "SELECT id,date,quantity1,quantity2,total,SUM(total) AS stotal,AVG(ROUND(total)) AS atotal FROM test WHERE type='pencil' AND MONTH(date)='$month' AND YEAR(date)='$year' ORDER BY id";
$r1 = mysql_query($q1);
```

Comment: hi, this returns one row only.